# scrollbar button js not working

Tags: javascript, scroll, scrollbar, scrollview, slide

I'm creating photo slides using simple scrollbar method but also adding js for left and right button to make it flexible to view slide horizontally.

Scrollbar is working just perfect but the bellow buttons doesn't seem to show any action. Can someone please guide me what's wrong in the coding? TIA

Here's what I am talking about: `[https://jsfiddle.net/sh27dyx3/1/]`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

scrollbar doesn't set `$("#slide").left`. jQuery's `offset().left` is just clever enough to tell you what is its offset. you need to update the parent's scrollbal scrollLeft property

https://jsfiddle.net/txth2usk/

by the way, i guess you could determine what image is at the leftmost position and then instead of `-100` and `+100` you could scroll to the next/previous sibling's offset, would be much cooler

Comment: your answer is so much nicer, i left his +100 constants in there